# BackdropFilter shows no blurring on WebViewX

Tags: flutter

Using the webviewx_plus package for rending a webpage.
BackdropFilter ImageFilter.blur() not showing blur on the WebView as desired according to the design, but shows blur to all other widgets (Container/Text/Image/etc)

```
Stack(
 children: [
  //Container(
  // width: 200,
  // height: 200,
  // color: Colors.green,
  // child: Text('This container works fine),
  //),
  WebViewX(
   width: double.maxFinite,
   height: double.maxFinite,
   ignoreAllGestures: true,
   initialContent: '<h2> Hello, world! </h2>',
   initialSourceType: SourceType.url,
   onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
    controller
     .loadContent('https://example.com');
    return webViewXController = controller;
   },
  ),
  BackdropFilter(
   filter: ImageFilter.blur(
    sigmaX: 20,
    sigmaY: 20,
   ),
   child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    color: Colors.pink,
    child: Text('Hello'),
   ),
  ),
 ]
)
```

Comment: Hi Did you solve the issue?